# Finding the most popular location

Tags: data-analysis

This feels really simple, but looking for some guidance to find the most popular location for orders.

I have three locations: Location A, Location B, and Location C.

Location A had 43 orders out of a population size of 239,762.
Location B had 11 orders out of a population size of 64,551.
Location C had 1 order out of a population size of 10.

The order rate in each location was 0.018%, 0.017% and 10.000%, respectively.

Obviously, Location C is an outlier, but how could I come up with a way of determining which the most popular location was for orders?

I want to be able to have a list of the most popular locations sorted from most popular to least popular, but putting Location C at the top of the list feels incorrect because the size of the population is so small.

Comment: Determine a minimum population, say 1,000.  Sort by order rate descending when population >= 1,000 and the number of orders descending when population < 1000.  Concatenate the sorted lists.